# jsoup selector syntax for an element with a particular direct child

Tags: jsoup

jsoup selectors allow you to specify a direct parent-child relationship and return the matching children:

```
  root.select("blockquote > div#foo").forEach(div -> div.remove());
```

You can use the `parent()` method to get back to the matched child's direct parent:

```
  root.select("blockquote > div#foo").forEach(div -> div.parent().remove());
```

Is there a straightforward way to have the selector *itself* return the parent from this matching direct parent-child pair?  Something along the lines of this (which doesn't work)?

```
  root.select("blockquote:has(> div#foo)").foreach(bq -> bq.remove())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
blockquote:has(blockquote > div#foo)
```

#### DEMOs

- [No direct child](http://try.jsoup.org/~bqHpBNFuN59x92u-XbB5bcod0rc)
- [Direct child](http://try.jsoup.org/~puqTmt8X26DPLT11IipVPYsBqeo)

Comment: That doesn't guarantee that the `div` is a *direct* child of the `blockquote`, though.

Comment: That also matches a `blockquote` containing a `span` containing a `div` containing a `p` containing a `blockquote` containing a `div#foo`.